# Convert Amazon transaction data for import into accounting system

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, pandas, e-commerce

At the end of each billing cycle, Amazon generates a raw transaction file for my store's orders that cycle. I am converting that raw transaction file into a .csv file to be imported into my accounting software. My converter program takes two input files.

The first input, the [Amazon data file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kMnQWBOL_t15I56etr0Zwq9UR7VZ-h5w/view?usp=sharing), contains hundreds of lines, and looks like this:

```
settlement-id   settlement-start-date   settlement-end-date deposit-date    total-amount    currency    transaction-type    order-id    merchant-order-id   adjustment-id   shipment-id marketplace-name    amount-type amount-description  amount  fulfillment-id  posted-date posted-date-time    order-item-code merchant-order-item-id  merchant-adjustment-item-id sku quantity-purchased  promotion-id
11774871501 2019-04-01 13:09:26 UTC 2019-04-07 14:54:57 UTC 2019-04-09 14:54:57 UTC 11591.38    USD                                                                     
11774871501                     Order   111-3282062-5204245 111-3282062-5204245     DW6NY7djJ   Amazon.com  ItemPrice   Principal   29.95   AFN 2019-04-03  2019-04-03 17:13:29 UTC 04346910081818          D0-FMT7-C3G9    1   
11774871501                     Order   111-3282062-5204245 111-3282062-5204245     DW6NY7djJ   Amazon.com  ItemPrice   Shipping    4.42    AFN 2019-04-03  2019-04-03 17:13:29 UTC 04346910081818          D0-FMT7-C3G9    1   
11774871501                     Order   111-3282062-5204245 111-3282062-5204245     DW6NY7djJ   Amazon.com  ItemFees    FBAPerUnitFulfillmentFee    -3.19   AFN 2019-04-03  2019-04-03 17:13:29 UTC 04346910081818          D0-FMT7-C3G9    1   
11774871501                     Order   111-3282062-5204245 111-3282062-5204245     DW6NY7djJ   Amazon.com  ItemFees    Commission  -4.49   AFN 2019-04-03  2019-04-03 17:13:29 UTC 04346910081818          D0-FMT7-C3G9    1   
11774871501                     Order   111-3282062-5204245 111-3282062-5204245     DW6NY7djJ   Amazon.com  ItemFees    ShippingChargeback  -4.42   AFN 2019-04-03  2019-04-03 17:13:29 UTC 04346910081818          D0-FMT7-C3G9    1   
11774871501                     Order   114-8130626-1298654 114-8130626-1298654     D7RCVz0SP   Amazon.com  ItemPrice   Principal   173.08  AFN 2019-04-03  2019-04-03 22:32:57 UTC 50221749590266          E6-0OOH-4ASK    1   
11774871501                     Order   114-8130626-1298654 114-8130626-1298654     D7RCVz0SP   Amazon.com  ItemFees    FBAPerUnitFulfillmentFee    -9.02   AFN 2019-04-03  2019-04-03 22:32:57 UTC 50221749590266          E6-0OOH-4ASK    1   
11774871501                     Order   114-8130626-1298654 114-8130626-1298654     D7RCVz0SP   Amazon.com  ItemFees    Commission  -25.96  AFN 2019-04-03  2019-04-03 22:32:57 UTC 50221749590266          E6-0OOH-4ASK    1   
…
```

The second input is a [CSV file that stores the necessary accounting codes](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pqBqXssA3gofyoZyr4duFm-skZsR9BLf/view?usp=sharing), which contains a few dozen lines, and looks like this:

```
combined-type,AccountCode,Description
Non-AmazonOrderItemFeesFBAPerUnitFulfillmentFee,501,Non-Amazon - Order - ItemFees - FBAPerUnitFulfillmentFee
Amazon.comOrderItemPricePrincipal,400,Amazon.com - Order - ItemPrice - Principal
Amazon.comOrderItemPriceShipping,403,Amazon.com - Order - ItemPrice - Shipping
Amazon.comOrderItemPriceShippingTax,202,Amazon.com - Order - ItemPrice - ShippingTax
…
```

I used Python 3 and Pandas.  Can you help me make this code bulletproof? My concern is the code does not catch errors and/or does not execute my intent.

Landmark 1:
Read in the settlement file (raw transaction file).
Read in the account codes file to match transactions to accounting codes.

Landmark 2:
Clean up the settlement file by collecting the summary data and converting the four columns into a combined column for comparison and matching to the account codes file.

Landmark 3:
Find the matching account code for each transaction and sum the total. So now we should have a summary amount for each account code.

Landmark 4:
Clean up the new combined dataframe into the proper template format for our accounting software. Export new file as .csv for uploading into accounting software.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.6
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Read in Amazon settlement - can be picked up by Python script later
az_data = pd.read_csv('/Users/XXX/Desktop/az_data.txt', sep='\t', header=0, parse_dates=['settlement-start-date', 'settlement-end-date'])
df = pd.DataFrame(az_data)

#Read in Account codes - this can be SQL storage later
acct_codes = pd.read_csv('/Users/XXX/Desktop/acct_codes.csv', sep=',', header=0)
df_accts = pd.DataFrame(acct_codes)

#Take summary data from first row of Amazon settlement and use as check-data
settlement_id = df.iloc[0,0]
settlement_start_date = df.iloc[0,1]
settlement_end_date = df.iloc[0,2]
deposit_date = df.iloc[0,3]
invoice_total = df.iloc[0,4]

#Drop summary row as it is no longer needed and doesn't match
df.drop(df.index[0], inplace=True)

#Replace blank values in 'marketplace-name' column with 'alt-transaction' so groupby doesn't skip those values. And replace all other blank values with 'NA' value
fillvalues = {'marketplace-name': 'alt-transaction'}
df.fillna(value=fillvalues, inplace=True)
df.fillna('NA', inplace=True)

#Create combined column to use as a key
df['combined-type'] = df['marketplace-name'] + df['transaction-type'] + df['amount-type']+ df['amount-description']

#Groupby combined column and take sum of categories
df_mod = df.groupby(['combined-type'])[['amount']].sum()

#Merge dataframes to get account codes and descriptions
df_results = df_mod.merge(df_accts, on='combined-type', how='left')

#Drop row from un-used account
df_results = df_results[df_results['combined-type'] != 'Non-AmazonOrderItemPricePrincipal']

#Rename columns to match Xero template
df_results.rename(columns={'amount':'UnitAmount'}, inplace=True)

#Drop the now un-needed combined-type column
df_results.drop(columns=['combined-type'], inplace=True)

#Add invoice template columns with data
df_results['ContactName'] = 'Amazon.com'
df_results['InvoiceNumber'] = 'INV_' + str(settlement_id)
df_results['Reference'] = 'AZ_Xero_Py_' + str(settlement_id)
df_results['InvoiceDate'] = settlement_start_date
df_results['DueDate'] = settlement_end_date
df_results['Quantity'] = 1
df_results['Currency'] = 'USD'
df_results['TaxType'] = 'Tax on Sales'
df_results['TaxAmount'] = 0
df_results['TrackingName1'] = 'Channel'
df_results['TrackingOption1'] = 'Amazon'

#Re-order columns to match template
all_column_list = ['ContactName','EmailAddress','POAddressLine1','POAddressLine2','POAddressLine3','POAddressLine4','POCity','PORegion','POPostalCode','POCountry','InvoiceNumber','Reference','InvoiceDate','DueDate','InventoryItemCode','Description','Quantity','UnitAmount','Discount','AccountCode','TaxType','TrackingName1','TrackingOption1','TrackingName2','TrackingOption2','Currency','BrandingTheme']
df_final = df_results.reindex(columns=all_column_list)

print (df_final.dtypes)

#Re-format the datetimes to be dates
df_final['InvoiceDate'] = df_final['InvoiceDate'].dt.date
df_final['DueDate'] = df_final['DueDate'].dt.date

#Export final df to csv
df_final.to_csv('/Users/XXX/Desktop/invoice' + str(settlement_id) + '.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I hope you'll get some great feedback.

Comment: Thanks @Alex , I am looking forward to learning!